# Issues with extensions interfering with the dock in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: upgrade, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, 19.04

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu version 19.04 and it was working relatively well. Today however, I attempted to install the dynamic panel transparency tool for it and now my favourite apps have disappeared. They are still being registered on my apps list as in my favourites but my dock is only displaying the show applications button.

I've attached some images to assist my issue:

Firefox, files, terminal etc are all on my favourites but not showing up:
[image: Firefox, files, terminal etc are all on my favourites but not showing up.]

I get this error flag in gnome-tweaks over the "Ubuntu dock" extension:
[image: I get this error flag in gnome-tweaks over the "Ubuntu dock" extension]

I also get this error when I click the "ubuntu dock" option at the bottom of the extensions page
[[image: I also get this error when I click the "ubuntu dock" option at the bottom of the extensions page]]

Really stuck as to how to fix this, I've already tried restarting the gnome shell but that didn't do anything. Been trying to reinstall 19.04 but to no avail.

Comment: Could you append to your question, the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps`

Comment: Here's the output: ['org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'spotify_spotify.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'steam.desktop', 'discord_discord.desktop', 'skypeforlinux.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop', 'firefox.desktop']

Answer (score 0):

In your Dash-to-Dock settings, under the tab Lauchers, enable the "Show Favorite Applcations":

[image]

Comment: I have those exact options switched on

Comment: K - I'm at a loss after that.